# Функция из dll возвращает неверные значения Python

Tags: python, delphi, dll, ctypes

Есть Dll(исходников нету), есть интерфейсный модуль к ней написанный на Delphi. Вызываю функцию:

```
function ProcessBonusListCountersPrint(vBonusCountersPrintQuery: TBonusCountersPrintQuery; var vListCountersPrint: TListCountersPrint): Integer; stdcall;

type TBonusCountersPrintQuery = packed record
     Card: array[0..15] of char;

type TListCountersPrint = packed record         
     Lines: array[0..PACKET_COUNTERS_PR_MAX_LINE_COUNT - 1] of TCounterLine;

type TCounterLine = packed record
     LineNo: word;
     IsLast: byte;
     Num_Counter: word;
     N_Counter: array[0..9] of char;
     Value_Counter: Cardinal;
```

(Описание структур, функций беру из интерфейса)

На Python реализовал так:

```
from ctypes import *

class TBonusCountersPrintQuery(Structure):
_fields_ = [("Card", c_char * 15)]

class TListCountersPrint(Structure):
_fields_ = [("Lines", TCounterLine * 20)]

class TCounterLine(Structure):    
_fields_ = [("LineNo", c_int),
            ("IsLast", c_byte),
            ("Num_Counter", c_int),
            ("N_Counter", c_char * 11),
            ("Value_Counter", c_int)]

packet_counters_pr_max_line_count = 20;
i = 0;

ProcessBonusListCountersPrint = libc.ProcessBonusListCountersPrint

ProcessBonusListCountersPrint.argtype = [TBonusCountersPrintQuery, POINTER(TListCountersPrint)]
ProcessBonusListCountersPrint.restype = c_int32

vBonusCountersPrintQuery = TBonusCountersPrintQuery()
vBonusCountersPrintQuery.Card = b'123456798'

vListCountersPrint = TListCountersPrint()

res = ProcessBonusListCountersPrint(vBonusCountersPrintQuery, byref(vListCountersPrint))
print('ProcessBonusListCountersPrint', res)

for i in range(packet_counters_pr_max_line_count):
    if vListCountersPrint.Lines[i].IsLast == 1:
        break
    print(vListCountersPrint.Lines[i].Num_Counter, vListCountersPrint.Lines[i].N_Counter.decode('cp1251'), vListCountersPrint.Lines[i].Value_Counter)
```

vListCountersPrint.Lines[i].N_Counter - возвращается правильное значение, а вот числовые значения из этой структуры все неверные. Числовые типы все пробовал, ни один не дал даже похожего результата.
Вопрос: как получить нужные мне данные?(в среде Borland Delphi 7 все работает)

Comment: Структура `TCounterLine` у вас упакована? Какая размерность у `c_int` в байтах? `N_Counter` у вас длинна почему-то 11 указана, а в Delphi - 10. Какой в питоне порядок расположения целых чисел в памяти? В Delphi `word` (2 байта) в памяти хранится так: первый байт младшая часть числа, второй старшая.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Совместил ответ от zed и tonal. В итоге получилась такая структура:

```
class TCounterLine(Structure):
_pack_ = 1
_fields_ = [("LineNo", c_short),
            ("IsLast", c_byte),
            ("Num_Counter", c_short),
            ("N_Counter", c_char * 10),
            ("Value_Counter", c_int)]
```

Всё заработало. Большое спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 4):

1. Структуры в Python надо объявлять с параметром `_pack_ = 1`, поскольку в Delphi они объявлены как `packed`.
2. Неправильно объявлены поля `Card` (15 байт, хотя в Delphi - 16) и `N_Counter` (11 байт, хотя в Delphi - 10).
3. В структуре `TCounterLine` в Python использованы неправильные типы для `LineNo` и `Value_Counter` (в Delphi `word` - это 2-х байтовое беззнаковое целое, в ctypes для этого есть тип `c_ushort`).

Answer (score 2):

Вот так будет правильно:

```
class TCounterLine(Structure):    
  _fields_ = [("LineNo", c_short), # LineNo: word;
        ("IsLast", c_byte), # IsLast: byte;
        ("Num_Counter", c_short), # Num_Counter: word;
        ("N_Counter", c_char * 10), # N_Counter: array[0..9] of char;
        ("Value_Counter", c_int)] # Value_Counter: Cardinal;
```